# How to swap the Registration_ID in GCM/FCM when users use a different smartphone?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, messaging

Basically, I want to cover the next scenario in my App.

I can make group's devices between users. Also, I could add or remove one user from those groups. What would happen if one user changed his smartphone, and I don't want to remove his registration_id in his groups and just swap it with a new one?

I've been reading the whole Google documentation but I didn't find anything. So the only think that I found was use a petition to remove the RegistrationID from all groups and then add again the new registration ID, but I see this really complicated and doesn't make any sense.

Do you know guys if is there the "best" way to do that?

Comment: it's not clear to me what you want or why you need it. typically a device group would have registration ids of all devices of a single user.

Comment: if a user replaces an old phone for a new one, or lose the old  one by stolen or something similar

Comment: then it's not a "swap", it's just a removal of a registration id from group and that can be done on the server. see https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/notifications#managing-device-groups-on-the-app-server

Comment: It's remove the last one and add a new one. so yeah, it's swap. I want to do this in just 1 REST Call :P

Answer (score 1):

I handle the scenario like registration on the server, what i do is check if user already registered and if registered i check if registration id is different to one stored, if is different I check all groups the user belongs to and call delete with old registration id and add with the new Id to each group, make sure update the database with the new registration id after/before.

Comment: This is exactly what I do in this moment, but as you said I have to do in this moment 2 calls to the GCM Server, the first one to remove the old Id, and the second one to add the new one.

But seem there is not an end point to do this in just 1 server call

Comment: As far as I know there is no end-point to add and remove at once, sorry